# Laravel 5.5, When updating a logo: Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

Tags: javascript, image, laravel-5.5

I have written some code to upload a logo (picture) into a radio station using a crud table, the uploading function works when creating a new radio station, now I have made a update function for the same crud table using the following code in the controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required',
        'logo' => 'nullable',

    ]);
    if ($request['logo'] === null) {
    Internetradiostations::find($id)->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('internetradiostationseditor.index')
        ->with('success','Internet radio station ge-updated');
    } else {
        $input['logo'] = time().'.'.$request->logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->logo->move(public_path('logos'), $input['logo']);

        $input['title'] = $request->title;
        $input['url'] = $request->url;
        Internetradiostations::find($id)->update($input);
        return redirect()->route('internetradiostationseditor.index')
            ->with('success','Internet radio station ge-updated');
    }
}
```

When executing the code I get the following error:

`Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string`

Anyone know how to solve this?, I have only changed create to update:
`Internetradiostations::create($input);`

To:

`Internetradiostations::find($id)->update($input);`

Comment: Are you sure the `logo` input has `type="file"`?

Comment: @Dmitry Added `type="file"` to form blade: ` {!! Form::file('logo', array('type' => 'file', 'class' => 'form-control' )) !!}, ` didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dmitry Thank you!, you were right, solved with changing the form opening of blade internetradiostationseditor.edit:

From:
   `{!! Form::model($internetradiostation, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['internetradiostationseditor.update', $internetradiostation->id]]) !!}`

To:
`{!! Form::model($internetradiostation, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['internetradiostationseditor.update',  $internetradiostation->id], 'files'=>true, 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}`